# My clock doesn't work

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, scheduling

I have this code. When I click on the clock, my alarm don't activate and not work. I have tried with `DynamicModule` and nothing. I don't know where is the error.

```
reloj = Dynamic[
   Refresh[ClockGauge[DateString["Time"], ImageSize -> 120, 
     LabelStyle -> {Darker@Black, 10.5, Bold}, 
     GaugeStyle -> {Red, Red, Black}, PlotTheme -> "Minimal", 
     TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], LabelStyle -> Bold, 
     GaugeLabels -> {"ROLEX", Placed[ "AMPM", {0.5, 0.35}]}, 
     GaugeMarkers -> "ThinArrowNeedle"], UpdateInterval -> 1]];

sound = EmitSound@
   Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "alarmbeep.mp3", "Sound"];

alarma = Dynamic@
   Panel[Row[{Column[{Control[{{h, "", "Hours"}, Range[25] - 1}], 
        Control[{{m, "", "Minutes"}, Range[61] - 1}], 
        Control[{{oo, True, "Alarm"}, {True -> "ON", 
           False -> "OFF"}}]}], 
      If[Refresh[DateList[], UpdateInterval -> 1][[4 ;; 5]] == {h, 
          m} && oo, sound]}], Background -> LightBlue];

EventHandler[reloj, 
 "MouseClicked" :> 
  Quiet@CreateDialog[Column[{Panel[alarma], ChoiceButtons[]}], 
    WindowTitle -> "CONFIGURE LA ALARMA"]]
```

Comment: I guess `sound` should be defined using `SetDelayed` instead of `Set` as the `EmitSound` is part of the definition of `sound`. Or you should call `EmitSound` inside `Dynamic`.

Comment: @Johu. When I called EmitSound inside Dynamic the sound don´t I can't stoped. This test I did it before and it did not work.

Comment: `Dynamic@Panel[
  Row[{Column[{Control[{{h, "", "Hours"}, Range[25] - 1}], 
      Control[{{m, "", "Minutes"}, Range[61] - 1}], 
      Control[{{oo, True, "Alarm"}, {True -> "ON", 
         False -> "OFF"}}]}], 
    If[Refresh[DateList[], UpdateInterval -> 1][[4 ;; 5]] == {h, m} &&
       oo, EmitSound@
      Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "alarmbeep.mp3", "Sound"]]}], 
  Background -> LightBlue]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `sound = EmitSound@...` evaluates immediately and `sound` is just `Null`. You should've heard it after initial <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you want it to be a 'reusable' sound you should use `SetDelayed` as suggested in comments:

   ```
   sound[] := EmitSound @ ...
   ```

   You don't need to use `[]` but I find it a good habbit to have functions/precedures called this way instead of just a symbol.

   Additional improvement, you can preimport the sound:

   ```
   With[ { s = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "alarmbeep.mp3", "Sound"] }
   , sound[]:=EmitSound @ s
   ]
   ```
2. Your alarm trigger is in the dialog panel so it won't work when the dialog is hidden. You need to keep it visible with the clock. Something like:

   ```
   EventHandler[
     DynamicWrapper[reloj,  If[Refresh[...]]
   , "MouseClicked" :>... 
   ]
   ```

Comment: problem solved, thanks@Kuba